# How efficient is pytail as compared to a shell tail running as subprocess (['tail','-f','filename.txt']) in a python script?

Tags: python, tail

How efficient is pytail as compared to a shell tail running as subprocess in a python script?

```
subprocess.Popen(['tail','-f','filename.txt'])
```

Comment: efficient in what sense?

Comment: 3. It's 3 efficient.

Comment: also `subprocess.call` will wait for the subprocess to finish and `tail -f` doesn't finish, use the `Popen` constructor and pass appropriate `stdout`.

Comment: @Kos in the sense of resource consumption. The pytail module i saw contains a busy polling file reads. I was wondering if there could be some other way to read the file updates....  till now tail -f is the best shot I've got. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It appears you should be using this: https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify - if you want a Python program to "follow" a file which is being appended or modified.

Comment: Thanks @John. I went through the code, it also contain  the subprocess which runs a shell command => 
 subprocess.Popen(options.command, shell=True)  .I was wondering if there was any python library which could follow the file without invoking a shell command.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the pyinotify code.  It does not use a shell command except in one very specific circumstance which won't affect you.

Answer (score 1):

I just got pytail working and as far as I can tell there is no option to follow a file as it grows so it's basically pointless in most use cases.  Just prints the last X lines.

To answer your question, not very.